# Microsoft SharePoint Online Management Shell issue

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, windows

I have SharePoint Online Power Management Shell version 16.0.8316.1200 installed on my laptop. Now I want to install latest version of it, but previous version of the shell is not overwriting neither it is getting uninstall.

When I run `Get-Module` command I can see installed version but when I try run `Uninstall-Module` I get error
[image]

After further digging I found that it is installed through **Program and Features** of **Control Panel**
[image]

I try to uninstall but it always ask me to for original package file to uninstall so I cannot uninstall it too. I am stuck over here. Can somebody help me from where I can download old version of msi so I can uninstall reinstall latest version
[image]

Somebody help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the all issue. I will explain it step by step

1. I cannot uninstall/upgrade SharePoint Online Management Shell

   a. I try to uninstall from PowerShell but it gives me error as bellow
   [image]

   b. Then I try to upgrade SharePoint Online Management Shell to upward version but it install another SharePoint Online Management Shell with newer version. Whenever I start SharePoint Online Management Shell it start with old version not with new. So I uninstall never version

   c. I downloaded newer version and try to install but it also give me error **The specified account already exists**

   [image]

   d. So I downloaded Microsoft Install Cleaner from h[ttps://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed](http://ttps://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/17588/windows-fix-problems-that-block-programs-being-installed-or-removed) and repaired  SharePoint Online Management Shell which repaired and patch registry of windows

   e. Finally I could install new version of SharePoint Online Management Shell and it overwrites old version and I can work on new version